# The ScaleTo parameter behaviour in the NReco.PdfRenderer.PdfToImageConverter in Windows

Tags: c#, nreco

I'm trying to render a scaled image using the code:

```
new PdfToImageConverter
{
    ScaleTo = 2200
}
.GenerateImage(
    "sample.pdf",
    1,
    ImageFormat.Png,
    "sample.pdf.png");
```

The code renders a good proportional image under Ubuntu, but a squared image under Windows.

The squared window has a white field:

[image]

Sample application:
https://github.com/sergei-voronkov/Test.NReco.ScaleTo

Also, the generated image is correct if I try to generate it using native poppler utility `pdftoppm.exe` under Windows:

```
pdftoppm.exe -png -aa yes -aaVector yes  -f 1 -l 1 -singlefile  -scale-to 2200 sample.pdf sample.pdf
```

The command line generates a proportional scaled image:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to specify "-aa yes -aaVector yes" options to get the same result?.. You can do that with "PdfToImageConverter.CustomArgs" property.

Comment: The command line is built by the NReco.PdfRenderer while it calls the pdftoppm. I've just copy it from process explorer during the NReco render process.

Comment: I've found out important information about the problem.
The archive 

https://github.com/sergei-voronkov/Test.NReco.ScaleTo/raw/master/Test.NReco.ScaleTo/NReco.vs.Origin.zip

Contains 2 folders.

The PdfRenderer is the folder being created during the NReco rendering.
I've put the sample.pdf to the folder and run

pdftoppm.exe -png -aa yes -aaVector yes  -f 1 -l 1 -singlefile  -scale-to 2200 sample.pdf sample.pdf

I've got the squared png.

The folder poppler contains original poppler binary modules.

I've done the same operation within the folder and got correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in the [version 1.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PdfRenderer/1.5.0).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is different because 'pdftoppm' versions are different.

On Windows, NReco.PdfRenderer uses poppler tools binaries that are shipped in the nuget package -- they are extracted on first use and there is no need to deploy them manually. The latest NReco.PdfRenderer includes poppler 21.03 release. In this version "-scale-to" parameter works differently, it always renders to square image; say, if ScaleTo=2000 then output always is 2000x2000. It seems this bug is already known and fixed: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1062. I'll check that, maybe it would be enough to prepare a new NReco.PdfRenderer release with the latest poppler tools binaries for Windows. As a temporary workaround, you may consider to use "Dpi" property to get better resolution for your output images.

On Linux you may choose what poppler tools version to install, and I guess in your case this version is older (like 0.68 or earlier), where "-scale-to" works correctly.

Comment: Thanks! When are you planning to release the new version with the bugfix?

Comment: Yes, I've already verified that this issue is already fixed in newer poppler versions.
A new NReco.PdfRenderer release (with updated poppler binaries) will be published in a few days.